# How can I iterate every odd or even properties in the object javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How can I iterate every odd or even properties from the object, when property keys are only strings, not numbers?

```
var object = {
    odd1: 'a',
    even2: 'b',
    odd3: 'c',
    even4: 'd'
};
```

//Edit: The keys are not duplicated.

Comment: Is `odd` & 'even` are key name?an object cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: this might be helpful for u . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119941/split-an-array-into-two-arrays-based-on-odd-even-position

Comment: Objects are like dictionaries: keys are strictly unique and unordered.

Comment: You actually don't need this, since object properties don't have any specific order, they can't be odd or even.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I tried to show it more clear for the readers and used the key names for odd and even, but it misleads the question. So I added numbers behind the keys. I hope it clarifies my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         var object = {
          odd1: 'a',
          even2: 'b',
          odd3: 'c',
          even4: 'd'
         };
        var od = [];  var ev = []; 
        var len = Object.keys(object).length;
        var keys = Object.keys( object );
       for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         if(i%2 === 0){
           ev.push(keys[i]); 
         }
        else {
          od.push(keys[i]);
        } 
      }
      alert("odd values are: "+od+" and even values are: "+ev );
```

Comment: if your purpose is to separate even and odd values then first u need to convert the keys of object into an array or if u want it for values that u can also do

Answer (score 1):

So for first, you can't have two properties with the same name. There is no order for the object properties. The latest one will override the previous value.

To iterate over the properties you can use [**Object#keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), which will return own properties of the object. And you can see that there are only 2 properties in the object.

```js
"use strict"

var object = {
    odd: 'a',
    even: 'b',
    odd: 'c',
    even: 'd'
};


Object.keys(object).forEach(prop => console.log(`${prop} - ${object[prop]}`));
```

Comment: Can you shead some light to the odd-even-order in an object?

Comment: Object properties don't have any order, they simply can't be ordered to odds and evens ...

Comment: "Odd an even" is an order.

Comment: You can't give a "working" ansewer to a question which doesn't have it. You're cheating OP here.

Comment: I show him how he can iterate over properties. I have said nothing about property order, which doesn't exists in the object. So if my answer is not clear, so it is **NOT** marked as the correct one. You can add your answer instead of commenting below mine.

Answer (score 0):

> iterate every odd or even properties from the object, when property
>   keys are only strings, not numbers?

This is essentially iterating over the entire object. For that you can use `for ..in`

```js
var object = {
  '1': 'a',
  '2': 'b',
  '3': 'c',
  '4': 'd'
};
for (var keys in object) {
  console.log(object[keys])
}
```