# How to print elements of an array in alternate order with the help of function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know that How can we print the elements of an array in a alternate order with the help of function in javascript?

array = [6,20,99,10,60,31,05,08];

result = [6,99,60,05]

Comment: [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract even elements of an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243355) and [split an array into two arrays based on odd/even position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119941)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for loop and increment i by 2

```js
let array = [2, 20, 5, 66, 5, 98, 4, 6];

function alternate(array) {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    console.log((i + 1) + ": " + array[i]);
  }
}
alternate(array);
```

Comment: let array = [2,20,5,66,5,98,4,6]

function alternate(array) { 
 
 for (i = 0; i < array.length; i+=2) {
  console.log((i+1) + ": " + array[i]);
 }

}

alternate();

Comment: You have to pass the array in the function call too. Check the edits

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - a [high-order **function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(higher-order_function)) in javascript. By using `filter` you can filter your elements via their index. If the index `i` modulo 2 is zero (ie `!(i % 2)`) then you can keep the element, and thus return true:

```js
const arr = [6,20,99,10,60,31,05,08],
res = arr.filter((_, i) => !(i % 2));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: use function please

Comment: `.filter` is a function?

Comment: He is expecting us to do his homework or maybe interview test :D

Comment: @shubhamd99 as `(_, i) => !(i % 2)` is a function (an arrow function) it's simila to: `function(_, i) { return !(i % 2);}`

Answer (score 1):

We want to traverse the array and use decent time complexity. To avoid looping more than once let's make our function do it in a single go. So we'll use an array helper. We also only want this to do something every other index. So we'll modulo it by 2, and if it is 0 we'll send it to the function. To make this have the same footprint as other common array functions we'll make it pass the same arguments it receives from forEach to the Function that gets passed.

```
function everyOther (array, fn) {
  array.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    if (!(index % 2)) fn(value, index, array);
  })
}
```

Now we just call it and do what we want!

```
everyOther([1,2,3], function (value) { console.log(value) }); // prints 1, 3
```

We could even make this strictly a print only of every other by wrapping it in a closure

```
function printEveryOther (array) {
  everyOther(array, function (value) { console.log(value) });
}

printEveryOther([1,2,3]) // 1, 3
```

Now you have an adaptable function that has a familiar footprint and even can be made to do other things!

Things that were made use of in this example:

- [Function declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)
- [Anonymous Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Okay now for some spice thanks to some more recent additions to JavaScript:

```
const everyOther = (a, f) => a.forEach((v, i) => !(i%2) && f(v,i,a));
const mapEveryOther = (a, f) => {
  const r = [];
  everyOther(a, (v, i) => r.push(f(v,i,a)));
  return r;
}
```

And now we've made another function entirely that instead returns an array

```
const doubleEveryOther = a => mapEveryOther(a, a => a + a);

doubleEveryOther([1,2,3]) // [2,6]
```

Concepts used:

- [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

There's still lots more to have fun with. Happy learning!